# Lenovo Ideapad 530S - Heavy throttling making CPU stuck at 1.58GHz clock speed - Any solutions?

Tags: cpu, lenovo-laptop, clock, clockspeed

I'm using a Lenovo Ideapad 530S, which has i5 8250U CPU and MX150 GPU.

Whenever I play a game such as Forza Horizon 3, the CPU clock starts with 3.38GHz, which is the maximum clock speed possible. The MX150 GPU usage rate shown in Task Manager also starts with 50~60%, which is adequate. However, after 1 or 2 minutes, the clock speed decreases heavily, and instantly, to 1.58GHz, as well as the GPU usage (%) decreases to around 30%. Of course the game starts to lag heavily, which makes me angry.

I tried undervolting the CPU using Intel XTU, to -100mV (over than that showed BSOD) which a lot of people recommended when I did some research on Google. Also, I found two settings in the BIOS menu called the DPTF (Dynamic Platform Thermal Framework) and System Performance, which were set as [Enabled] and [Quiet Mode] in default. I changed those settings to [Disabled] and [Performance Mode] and restarted the computer.

However, the throttling still occurs. Hopefully, I found this thread which shows an interesting(?) solution.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-Yoga-Series-Notebooks/CPU-Throttling-on-Intel-8th-Gen-Yoga-520/td-p/3917668

Therefore, for the final solution, I tried using ThrottleStop and set up the Speed Shift EPP value to 156 (default was 128), keeping the CPU voltage offset value. When I launched the game with ThrottleStop turned on, the CPU clock remained around 2.40GHz even after a few minutes, which was a good sign. However, the GPU still remains around 30% and the game speed is slower, compared to the moment when the CPU clock is 3.38GHz. I also tried using AfterBurner from MSI and increased the clock speed for the MX150 GPU, but it didn't work on increasing the game speed.

Any ideas to keep the CPU clock rate around the maximum rate, or disabling the thermal throttling??

Comment: Clean out fans and heat sinks, replace thermal pads and make sure heat sinks are secure. Use a laptop cooling pad with fans. Cleaning the machine might need you to open it up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the turbo boost power max. I found out that it is set to 8W at my 330s with the same CPU. With only 8W the CPU cannot do much more than 1,5Ghz. Check your temps and bring it close to 15W. And you can get arouns 2,5Ghz all core clock... But it comes at a price.. Called bad thermal (~80 °C)